# How can I order an Ev3 gyro in Europe

Tags: shopping, ev3

I just bought the Ev3 kit, knowing that the gyro sensor is not included. I obviously want a gyro sensor, perhaps also the ultrasonic sensor. Is there any official channel to order them in Europe? All I can find is US-delivery-only and schools-only sites.

Comment: You may want to check with the LEGO customer service if they can help; it could be that the part itself is available. In any case, give them a call, they're usually very friendly. Also, note that since we're very early in the life of EV3, it could be that options are limited at the moment but may expand in the future. I fully expect the battery to be available on shop@home, for example, and I don't see why the gyro sensor wouldn't be.

Comment: I can't comment since I signed up for real with another address than earlier. Thank you both for the help, I will contact customer service to show interest. I probably have to go with ebay anyway to get it before Christmas.

Answer (score 2):

The EV3 Gyro Sensor now appears to be on "general release" and available in both US and UK stores:
http://shop.lego.com/en-GB/EV3-Gyro-Sensor-45505 - these seem to be available in most EU countries the LEGO Shop ships to.

---

You can order the gyro sensor from the UK Lego Education site http://education.lego.com/en-gb/lego-education-product-database/mindstorms-ev3/45505-gyro-sensor.

OR

If you look at the shipping options in the US Educational site, it will ask you a series of questions to determine if the item can be shipped to your area. If no other options are available, they will ship to you for a fee and ask you to approve the shipping fee before they send it out. It looks like you can get the parts from Lego if you want them bad enough.

Comment: The UK site does not ship outside UK
http://shop.legoeducation.com/gb/page/terms-24/ and the problem with the US site is twofold:
- There are two distributors in my country. One sells toys for daycares, it does not have the gyro. One has their catalogues behind password access.
- Trying to order at the US site to get the shipping charge estimate, I cannot enter any meaningful information since it will only accept a US state and phone number. If nothing turns up I will go for the ebay listing. Long live the third-party entrepreneur. :)

Comment: The same goes for Belgium as well, actually; buying directly from LEGO is not possible and official distributors usually only deal with schools.

Comment: I just called the 800 number to find out if there is a process for shipping overseas and was politely told that they "avoid it if at all possible." They really should take that option out of their Shipping Wizard.