# NXT or EV3 gyro sensor

Tags: mindstorms, nxt, ev3

Do NXTs or EV3s have gyro sensors or built-in gyro sensors? How can I know the direction of the robot?

Comment: You might want to take a look at the answer to [What are all the different accessories for an NXT](http://bricks.stackexchange.com/a/862/56) for "1st party" options, or [What are all the 3rd party accessories for an NXT](http://bricks.stackexchange.com/a/972/56). As you can see in the [this answer](http://bricks.stackexchange.com/a/2610/56) LEGO now sell an official Gyro Sensor for the EV3, but I believe you'll need to use the Educational version of the software to access this sensor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

LEGO doesn't make a gyro sensor for NXT, but Hitechnic sells a [**gyro third party product**](http://www.hitechnic.com/cgi-bin/commerce.cgi?preadd=action&key=NGY1044) and Mindsensors has a [**combo gyro/accelerometer/compass (IMU)**](http://www.mindsensors.com/index.php?module=pagemaster&PAGE_user_op=view_page&PAGE_id=158). Both can be used with EV3, and LEGO also has a [**gyro sensor**](http://shop.lego.com/en-US/EV3-Gyro-Sensor-45505), included in the [**Education kit**](https://shop.education.lego.com/legoed/education/LEGO+MINDSTORMS+Education+EV3/EV3+Core+Set+Charger/5003400&isSimpleSearch=true)

Comment: Do you still need to use the Education version of the software to use the Gyro Sensor? I see it's now available stand-alone from the LEGO Shop.

Comment: For a while, blocs needed to use gyro or US distance sensors on home edition are a available for download. Gyro: http://www.lego.com/en-us/mindstorms/downloads/ev3-blocks/gyro/ and US-sensor: http://www.lego.com/en-us/mindstorms/downloads/ev3-blocks/ultrasonic/

Comment: Cheers, good to know :)